# Gradle sync failed: Connection refused: connect after proxy configured

Tags: android, android-studio

So I'm having a connection error with Gradle, even after setting up my proxy. I'm trying to build a project downloaded off GitHub. I loaded it and when I try to build I get the error `Gradle sync failed: Connection refused: connect`. I made sure I set up my proxy configuration, as that is usually what causes this problem. When I run `Check connection` in the Proxy Settings, it comes back successful. I even created a new project with the same exact `gradle.properties`, and it was able to download all the Gradle files.

Any ideas why this is happening for an already existing project?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you accessing from a laptop on a docking station perchance? Also, has it *ever* worked, or are you setting up Android Studio for the first time? One more thing: when was the last time you updated your network drivers? (The reason I asked is I had a similar problem that ended up being caused by my network drivers being out of date).

Comment: This is a docked laptop, I just reinstalled Android Studio after upgrading to Windows 10, and I'd hope the network drivers were updated when I got Windows 10, but I'll be sure to check.

I can't imagine it being a network issue though, as the connection is working on that brand new project. I'll try your suggestions though, just in case. Thanks.

Comment: I want to say that it was my NIC driver that was the problem, but I'm not positive. (I wasn't on Windows 10 yet at the time that I had the problem). The weird thing is that it seemed like other things were working OK other than the fact that Gradle sync would try to sync for like 10 minutes and then time out. It's worth a try either way, though. I stumbled on the issue by accident when I was doing an update for an unrelated issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a problem created by the `gradle.properties` file in Android Studio.

I do not use HTTP Proxy for any of my project while refreshing, syncing or building my Gradle and that's where the problem lied.
The project I cloned and then imported in the Android Studio had its own `gradle.properties` file where the proxy were set according to the someone else's configuration. I just deleted those five lines of code for proxy set-up in the `gradle.properties` file and just refreshed the gradle build again and it worked just fine for me.

These five lines were extra in my case:

```
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyHost=172.16.30.20
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
systemProp.https.proxyHost=172.16.30.20
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
```

So I guess there might be a proxy configuration in `gradle.properties` file that you might have to change according to your default proxy configuration.

Hope it helps.